# SQL Server : get date range and number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have 4 columns (two columns filter) and one column date and one column flag.
For a combination of column 1 and column 2, and the open flag, I want to find the open date, the close date and number of days where it was open.

Here is my example and what I want to find with SQL is with the blue/grey color

[image]

Comment: Sample data as **well formatted** `text`, or even better DDL and DML statements, Expected results and your attempt(s) will help us help you. Please don't expect the users here to transcribe your data, as it's very unlikely they will.

Comment: So far what have you come up with other than data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEDIFF()` function as shown below if you have already two dates available as `OpenDate` and `CloseDate` in your case.

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY, OpenDate, CloseDate) as NumberOfOpenDays from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a gaps-and-islands problem -- but the islands are already defined by `opendt` (and perhaps `col1` and `col2`).

So, you can just use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, opendt order by effectivedt)
```